# Displaying the value of a variable in PyClips

Tags: python-2.7, clips, expert-system, pyclips

**I have been trying to print the value of a variable in PyClips without any success.Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code.**

**Instead of "Are you observative" it prints "Are you ?name"**

```
def clips_raw_input(prompt):
    return clips.String(raw_input(prompt))

clips.RegisterPythonFunction(clips_raw_input, "input")


clips.Assert("(quality observative) ")
clips.Assert("(quality communicative) ")
clips.Assert("(quality emotionally-stable) ")
clips.Assert("(has human true)")

r1 = clips.BuildRule(
       "what-are-qualities",
       """(quality ?name)
       (not (has ?name ?))""",
        """(bind ?response (python-call input Are you ?name))
       (assert (has ?name ?response))""")
```

**Any help will be appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import clips
>>> def clips_raw_input(prompt):
...         return clips.String(raw_input(prompt))
... 
>>> clips.RegisterPythonFunction(clips_raw_input, "input")
>>> r1 = clips.BuildRule(
...        "what-are-qualities",
...        """(quality ?name)
...        (not (has ?name ?))""",
...        """(bind ?response (python-call input (str-cat "Are you " ?name "? ")))
...        (assert (has ?name ?response))""")
>>> clips.Reset()
>>> clips.Assert("(quality observative) ")
<Fact 'f-1': fact object at 0x10450b330>
>>> clips.Assert("(quality communicative) ")
<Fact 'f-2': fact object at 0x10450b360>
>>> clips.Assert("(quality emotionally-stable) ")
<Fact 'f-3': fact object at 0x10450b3f0>
>>> clips.Assert("(has human true)")
<Fact 'f-4': fact object at 0x10450b450>
>>> clips.Run()
Are you emotionally-stable? yes
Are you communicative? no
Are you observative? yes
3
>>> clips.PrintFacts()
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (quality observative)
f-2     (quality communicative)
f-3     (quality emotionally-stable)
f-4     (has human true)
f-5     (has emotionally-stable "yes")
f-6     (has communicative "no")
f-7     (has observative "yes")
For a total of 8 facts.
>>>
```